# Create a Multi-dimensional Array by Adding an Array into another Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have several populated arrays:

```
childArray0 = ["A","B","C"];
childArray1 = ["Airplane","Boat","Car"];
childArray2 = ["Asparagus","Beet","Carrot"];
```

When I add these three arrays into a empty array:

```
emptyArray[0] = childArray0;
emptyArray[1] = childArray1;
emptyArray[2] = childArray2;
```

I can't access the entries of the child arrays:

```
console.log(emptyArray[1][2]);
```

The above code comes back as undefined. However, this:

```
console.log(emptyArray[1]);
```

Shows me: `["Airplane","Boat","Car"]`. How can I access the entries of the child arrays? Can't you store populated arrays into the entries of another array in this manner?

Comment: does it not tell you that `childArray` and `emptyArray` is undefined? you're not using a keyword to define them. `var`, `let`, or `const`

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me in the console, the only problem I could see was you needed to initialize `emtptyArray` with an empty array before adding rows to it:

```
emtptyArray = [];
emtptyArray[0] = childArray0;
emtptyArray[1] = childArray1;
emtptyArray[2] = childArray2;
```

Otherwise you'll get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: emtptyArray is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```